# changing from classic asp to php - benefits?

Tags: language-agnostic

i've worked with classic asp so far and want to change to php (instead of asp.net)

could someone explain the main benefits from php over asp/asp.net?

thanks

Comment: ASP and ASP.NET are completly different. So you want to compare to ASP? And in my point of view PHP is quit the same as classical asp.

Comment: Just for clarification then ... you are asking for a three way comparison between ASP (VB / JScript / et alia) ASP.NET (C# / VB.NET / F# / et alia) and PHP?

Comment: Understand that this is akin to asking "I've worked with phillips-head screwdrivers before and want to change to flat-head screwdrivers.  What are the main benefits of one over the other?"  They're tools.  For any given project, use the correct tool(s).  No one is inherently better than another.

Comment: i forgot to mention that i decided to change from classic asp to php rather than asp.net :)

Comment: @David -- actually, it's more akin to asking "I've worked with common household tools before.  I want to switch over to power tools, so I'm buying a complete workshop from someone on Craig's List - can you compare my toolbox with this guy's workshop?  (Oh, and how do they stack up against the machine shop of the carpenter's union down the street?)"

Comment: @David, @Sean: I think you are both absolutely right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a definitive answer for this question as most of the items are going to boil down to your own style.  And I have used quite a bit of both in my professional career.  I just like c# better.

Both technologies are used to build web pages.

Both are highly flexible and provide you the capabilities to do whatever you want in a web site.

Both have idiosyncrasies that just take time to understand and get comfortable with.

Both have a large following and can be deployed just about anywhere.

Both have good database and security support.

You can shoot yourself just as easily with one as the other.

At the end of the day, the only real difference I can come up with is that the .Net languages are usually precompiled prior to deployment and therefore enjoy compile time checks and static code analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [PHP vs ASP: An in-depth Comparison](http://www.mybestratedwebhosting.com/best-web-hosting-tips/php-vs-asp-an-in-depth-comparison.html).

PHP has much more to offer than ASP which is why it powers sites like facebook and yahoo.

Comment: ASP.NET has similar abilities as PHP.

Comment: @Anton - correction: asp has similar abilities as php, asp.net is a completely different world

Comment: @Andrey: I fail to see the correction.  Name one "ability" that php has that .net doesn't.

Comment: @fire: it should be noted that what facebook has is as close to PHP as .net is to classic asp.  They completely changed it.

Comment: @Chris: it's not about "abilities" - in the end all those frameworks do is render html :) It's about flexibility in doing so and I think asp.net beats crap out of php/asp on that

Answer (score 0):

Main benefit of PHP is cheaper hosting.

Comment: Um.  No.  Hosting costs of both seem to be exactly the same.

Comment: Licensing costs will be different, if you go with your own data center. Php runs free LAMP stack - no license needed; asp/asp.net runs windows stack - big buck required :)

Comment: @Andrey: It's been proven quite a few times that over the life of an application the difference between supposedly "free" and "paid for" software is either negligible or non-existent.

Comment: @Chris - this is why I'm a strong supporter of asp.net :)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: all below is IMHO. 
The only benefit of php vs asp.net I see is that it runs on open source LAMP stack, so if you want to get a job in a startup php skills might be more demanded than asp.net.
Other than that, asp.net beats php on ease of implementation and flexibility. So being a biased asp.net developer, I would advise you to look into asp.net instead of php.